# Slider Does Not Move To Correct Page

Tags: javascript, jquery

List:

On this [website](http://www.dancecityperformingarts.com) the slider is not working the way I had desired.
Hoping someone can help.

When you click on the name of the dance class the slider moves, but does not move to the page that has the dance class description.

When you click on the "details" portion, it takes you to the page that has the class description, but the slider does not move to the correct picture.

Can anyone tell me how, if it can be, corrected.

I am very new to html coding, and;
I apologize if this is not phrased correctly or if additional information is needed.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: so clicking on class name, should redirect you  to same page wich details redirects?

Comment: @vinayakj **https://tonicdev.com/npm/jrcarousel**???

Comment: @PraveenKumar no, it only appears to, look at the names of the classes vs the pictures, like click on ballet and note that the picture is not of a ballet class.

Comment: @DelightedD0D Oh okay...

Comment: Is there any real reason you are using jquery-1.3.2 instead of a newer version??

Comment: @PraveenKumar I thought so at first too, took me a minute to see it :)

Comment: @DelightedD0D No buddy... It really works well... `:P`

Comment: @PraveenKumar yes tonicdev gives the error, I had contacted the npm, they says tonicdev isnt fully supported, but if your package works locally then its fine

Comment: @vinayakj Awesome, you are great! `:)`

Comment: @PraveenKumar you really liked the plugin?, thanks..

Comment: @PraveenKumar Maybe im looking at it wrong, I feel like the picture in this screenshot should be of a jazz class http://prntscr.com/98exs7 , Maybe the last picture is just missing?

Comment: @DelightedD0D I see the same. So I am not good with dances. `:P`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I think Im just being thrown off by the fact that the last one is not a picture of a class at all but details about the business that are shown when you click on Jazz class for some reason

Comment: See if the carousel plugin provides the callback function on slide shown event, if so programmatically click the details of that slide, whenever you click on the bar it would first show you the slide and then takes you to the details page. Code is minified on the site so not able to get to the event handler code.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, you are right.  The classes and the pictures do not match.  I am trying to fix that problem.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I could not find a picture of a jazz class right off.  Thus, the business description.  I will change that in the near future.

Comment: @lazerz69 That actually confused us bro!!! That was an ouch!

Comment: @DelightedD0D, Would be willing to use a newer version.  I am very new at this, so not up on the current versions.

Comment: For now, just pretend the business description is of a jazz class.

Comment: I need to get the class descriptions to match, (slide), with the proper picture.

Comment: And you want the right one to show when you navigate to the page right?

Comment: @DelightedD0D.  Yes please.  Would like the right picture to show with the correct class description.  Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: Thanks to all who have responded.